# how to add button in tab panel in ext js 3.2.0

Tags: extjs

I have a tab panel with multiple tabs. Now I want to add a button which will redirect me to a new window on clicking the button in tab Panel. Can someone tell how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom button to `tabBar`:

```
tabBar: {
    width: '100%',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: "Redirect",
        handler: function () {
          window.redirect...
        }
    }]
}
```